# How can I get access to data inside an passed object?

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently, I struggle with using data that is passed to a newly created Object.
When I create the new Object I pass some data to it that looks similar to this:

```
 { id: 1, name: 'Burger', price: 3, quantity: 1 },
 { id: 1, name: 'Pizza', price: 2, quantity: 2 }
```

Here is the class:

```
// create the Object somewhere in the code
return new Table(data);

export class Table {

meals: Meals;

constructor(meals: {}) {

    this.meals = meals;
    console.log(meals);
  }
```

The browser:

[image]

I would like to be able to call the properties of the class to use the data.
**e.g: meal.quantity**

Would be great if someone could tell me how I can get access to the data inside the objects. Thanks!

Comment: typescript is a strongly typed language. You need to define either an interface or a type so you can do that and not have the IDE complain. Sure, you could use `any` but that is not recommended unless the type is out of your control completely.

Comment: If I were you I would do some research on Typescript and type safety which is one of the main reasons that typescript exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, I believe you should look more into Typescript [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) ([advanced](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)).

That being said, I believe in your situation you cannot access the property with the compiler because you are telling the compiler that `meals: {}` is an anonymous object.

Try changing the type specified in the constructor as

```
constructor(meals: Meals) {
  ...
}
```

...assuming `Meals` is something similar to

```
export interface Meals {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  price: number, 
  quantity: number,
}
```